# Is my interpretation if this signal diagram correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, signal-processing

Is my interpretation of the following signal diagram correct?
[image: Signal Diagram]

\begin{eqnarray}
Z &=&-2X + Y\\
W &=& 2Y + X
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Yes, it looks correct

Comment: Yes, I think so too!

Comment: Yeah you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct! You have interpreted it properly.